# Yii 1.1 - SoapServer::SoapServer(url): failed to open stream

Tags: soap, yii, php-5.6

I'm migrating a service that uses SoapServer class, but when i made a request, i'm facing this error:

> SoapServer::SoapServer("url of my server"): failed to open stream:
>   HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error

I was using digital ocean droplet and have to resize to a another digital ocean droplet and i'm having this problem.

I'm using apache 2.4 and php5.6 with the yii 1.1 framework.

Comment: are you using pointing to your server using "localhost"?

Comment: No, i'm not. I'm using the public domain.

Comment: ping the domain from the server, most probably your server is unable to resolve the domain